# Cannot GET 404 err when refreshing pages if url has multiple subpaths

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

My frontend is React/Redux with a backend API in PHP. I am using Webpack with historyApiFallback enabled:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true
  }
```

I am using `redux-persist` to make refreshing work. I am able to refresh the page if the url is : `localhost:8000/summary` or any url which has only one path, but if the url has multiple subpaths, like so: `localhost:8000/summary/customers`, I get the Cannot GET 404  err.

My routes are defined like so:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path ="summary" component={SummaryItems} />
        <Route path ="summary/customers" component={AllCustomersSummary} />     
        //more routes    
    </Route> 
);
```

I looked at other answers but the suggested solution(enabling `historyApiFallback`) is not working in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

1.Create an `.htaccess` file in the root directory and add the following:

```
    RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Note that `index.html` is the homepage file(the file containing your react app), for me it was `home.php`. 
To my understanding(please correct me if I am wrong) the above solves the problem because when you refresh the page, a request is sent to the server with the url, which does not exist on the server, so the server sends back the homepage which contains your react app.

**Note: This solution does not work on localhost.**

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you can simply specify

```
<Route path ="customers" component={AllCustomersSummary} />
```

without using multiple subpaths and then visit it directly like `localhost:8000/customers`

And `historyApiFallback` is required when you use `history={browserHistory}`.

**UPDATE:**

Try an make use of Route handler to work on subroutes

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
      <Route path ="/summary" handler={SummaryItems} />
        <Route path ="/summary/customers" handler={AllCustomersSummary} />     
        //more routes    
    </Route> 
);
```

This should work

Comment: That would work for just this particular instance, but I have other instances where it is necessary to have subpaths, such as  retrieving promotions available for a particular customer.

Comment: How would that instance look like.

Comment: `domainname.com/promos/userNum`.
Or if a particular item is to be viewed :

`domainname.com/user/items/itemName`, 
The subpaths are necessary so that the url can be given to other people and they see the data right away